# mod_rewrite simple variable to page with renamed variable

Tags: mod-rewrite

If possible how do I do this in mod_rewrite...

```
http://site.com/var=123
```

to

```
http://site.com/page.php?x=123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in the .htaccess file in your document root

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^var=(.+)$ /page.php?x=$1 [L]
```

If you want query strings to get passed along, add a `QSA` to the brackets (so it looks like `[L,QSA]`. That'll make is to requests for **http://site.com/var=123?something=else** will get rewritten to **/page.php?x=123&something=else**